# HighCharts : How to add or remove "chart context menu" from chart container?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, contextmenu

Is there any property in highcharts that I can use to remove the chart context menu (the one looks like a hamburger menu on the right hand side) appears in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamarasekera/9tqwo4c8/3/) column chart using javascript?

Is this option comes in highchart by default? I also have a line chart but in that one there was no chart context menu by default. Also if I want to add a chart context menu to that line chart how can I do it?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {
          newValue = Math.random() * 100;
          series.update({
            data: [newValue],
          }, true)
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9]

  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6]

  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9]

  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4]

  }]
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just Include `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>`

you can enable or disable it by adding [buttonOptions](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/6.0.3/exporting.buttons.contextButton.enabled). Defaults to **true**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
});
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {
          newValue = Math.random() * 100;
          series.update({
            data: [newValue],
          }, true)
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan'
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.2,
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9]

  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6]

  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9]

  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4]

  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to disable the chart context menu in column chart. But adding this in the code didn't help me to add a chart context menu in the spline chart. Is this option not supported by spline chart or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I updated this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/com43tqb/ with navigation option and it works without any issue. I cannot figure out what has gone wrong in my code.

Comment: Yeah. When it's isolated it does. But in my project it does not. My original project has two charts. A bar chart as well as a spline chart. I can't figure out yet why it doesn't work like this in my project.

Comment: Okay I figured out the problem. I've included the script files in the wrong order.

Comment: @IsharaAmarasekera Okay, fine

Comment: @IsharaAmarasekera if this answer helped you. please accept it

Comment: Done ! Sorry it took longer. I got away with work. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the context menu in high charts as per the [discussion](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40573)

The context menu button comes from exporting module. To not show it, do not add the module script:

```js
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

**(or)**

we can disable it by hiding the `highcharts-contextmenu` class which is present in the `exporting.js` using javascript

**Example in JQuery**

```js
$(".highcharts-contextmenu").hide()
```

And to enable it on certain scenarios we can do vise-versa

```js
$(".highcharts-contextmenu").show()
```